# How to fill identity gaps while inserting data on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

First of all I would like to say that I know why and how the SQL Identity feature works caching the identity values that are going to be used and that it's not expected to be gapless. So, after a server restart (for example), [it can jump 1000/10000 values depending on the identity data type](https://web.archive.org/web/20160822054721/https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/failover-or-restart-results-in-reseed-of-identity), and I do know that the identity should be meaningless.

However, many years ago, I developed a link shortener on an old SQL Server version that didn't behave like the above. This link shortener uses the Id column to generate the shortened part of url.

After upgrading the SQL Server version, the gaps started to appear.

The table containing the links to be shortened is similar to the following (notice the gaps):

```
Id     | Url
---------------------------------
1      | http://foo.bar
2      | http://bar.foo     
10001  | http://google.com
20001  | http://stackoverflow.com
```

My application is then shortening the above links as the following (this is not a database table):

```
Id     | ShortenedUrl
---------------------------------
1      | foo.bar/a 
2      | foo.bar/b
10001  | foo.bar/fZ2sh
20001  | foo.bar/bbSz1
```

(Just to illustrate, the algorithm it's not as simple as 1 = a, 2 = b)

So now I have a problem: The whole point of having a link shortener is to generate short links. Now I have 4 more characters than necessary.

I can't just use the `row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [ID])` function because I already have data in production that would be lost/misgenerated.

What are my possibilities regarding ways to use the gaps while generating the next shortened links?

More information:

I can create another column that imports data from the Id column (for the already existent ones) and starts to use a new logic through a procedure (called for data insertion) locking whatever needs to be locked to get the next available gap number for the new rows.

This table is currently only being used on a MVC application (no foreign keys pointing to it). Data is currently being inserted through direct inserts, but I can update the application to use a (new) procedure. In other words, the table structure can change, the information contained in them can't.

Comment: Don't use `IDENTITY`; it's doing exactly as it's intended to do. If you want sequential numbers, you would be better off using a `SEQUENCE`.

Comment: @Larnu I already have data in production, this is legacy. If I had to create this table again today I would use SEQUENCE, indeed.

Comment: How could we possibly help you? We don't know how you are shortening your urls. All you said is they are too long because the identity values are larger than you want. But you can't change the data. Sounds to me like you are stuck. Either start using a sequence now or deal with urls that are as short as you want.

Comment: You could reseed to `IDENTITY`, *however*, it **will** try to reuse values that have already been reused. So, for example, if you have number 1-100, and then 1000-2015, if you reseed to 100 the next number used will be 101. Once, however, number 999 is used SQL server *will* try to use 1000, which will likely cause a key violation. It will then continue to try to use 1001, 1002, 1003,...2015 and then it'll finally succeed again at 2016.

Comment: You can use the [`LEAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) window function to find gaps in the sequence, but as the column is an `IDENTITY` column you'll need to turn `IDENTITY_INSERT ON` to insert values where the gaps are etc. It's not going be a clean solution.

Comment: If this is legacy, and you are unwilling or unable to change the design, you can use trace flag 272 to disable identity preallocation and revert back to the old behavior. Note that this is server-wide, needs a restart and has worse insert performance. From SQL Server 2017 onwards, this can be done cleaner on a per-database basis with the `IDENTITY_CACHE` option. This is not a solution to prefer for the long term, of course (that would be not using an identity, as others have mentioned).

Comment: @SeanLange I added more information to the question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Would you consider a completely different approach like 1) a classic hashing algorithm?  2) generating all of your short-links now, and then assigning URLs to them later. Then you don't need a less-efficient algorithm for calculating a short URL?

Comment: @MaxSzczurek I didn't have time to test it yet but I believe I'll have some problems with concurrency using it, won't I? I have to test it to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

One option is replacing the identity with a [sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). You'll still need to fix the bad data, but this lets you keep the URL separate from the key.

But from what I'm seeing the existing shortener needs some work.
**With a good algorithm, there's no reason for the value `20001` to require more than 3 characters.**
If you use two extra "special" characters, you can get to 64 possible values for each character in the shortened url (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and our specials . and _), which is enough to store six bits of data. We already have base-64 encoding this way, but since you only have digits you can get even more efficient.

Take a number like `20001`, convert it to binary:

```
100111000100001
```

Pad zeros to the left so the number of binary digits is a multiple of six:

```
000100111000100001
```

Break it into groups of six:

```
000100  111000   100001
```

Each of those groups should map to single possible character. To get the original ID#, do the same thing in reverse.

With this scheme, you'll get to `262143` before you need to add the 4th character to your URLs, `16777215` before you add the 5th character, and `1073741823` before you add the 6th.

For fun, here's some C# code to make the conversion:

```cs
private static char[] charMap = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
                                 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J',
                                 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T',
                                 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
                                 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
                                 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
                                 'y', 'z', '.', '_'};

public static string GetURLKey(int id)
{
    if (id <= 0) return "0";

    var bt = new byte[32];
    int pos = 32;
    while (id > 0)
    {
        pos--;
        bt[pos] = (byte)(id % 2);
        id >>= 1;
    }
    var bts = new Span<byte>(bt, pos, 32-pos);

    var r = 6 - (bts.Length % 6);
    if (r == 6) r = 0;

    return string.Create((bts.Length + r) / 6, bts.ToArray(), (span, arr) =>
    {
        int curChar = 0, charPos = r, bitArrPos = 0, curVal = 0;

        while (bitArrPos < arr.Length)
        {
            while (bitArrPos < arr.Length && charPos < 6)
            {
                curVal *= 2;
                curVal += (int)arr[bitArrPos];

                bitArrPos++;
                charPos++;
            }
            span[curChar] = charMap[curVal];
            curVal = 0;
            charPos = 0;
            curChar++;
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Shorteners often do not go for the densest mapping possible over a simple increment, because this opens up some avenues for exploits/abuse by making it too easy to guess URLs and access them before they're ever intended to be accessed. This can become especially dangerous when combined with a predictable way to trigger their generation. This isn't always a problem, nor is it always possible to completely close these holes if you're using shorteners to begin with, but just to point out why a "good" algorithm isn't necessarily "best".

Comment: There were other requirements besides that, like ignoring some letters to avoid urls like: foo.bar/cunt. The values that I described on my question are just dummy data too.